# How can customize Sublime Text's date format

Tags: sublime-text-2

When I do `date<tab>` or even `d<tab>` Sublime inserts date in format like this:

```
2014-02-24 10:31
```

It happens in every mode, so I guess it's not mode-linked.

I like that, but I'd like to customize this format. Where is this function defined?

Comment: you must have some sort of plugin installed, this is not a built-in feature of Sublime.

Comment: Can I find which plugin it is? It works in all modes.

Comment: Look for plugins with `date` or `datetime` in the name.

Comment: I have very few plugins and nothing like that, I tried grepping sources of plugins for any reference to `date` or `time`, but nothing seemed relevant.